# ZBarReaderViewController, view controllers hierarchy and others

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, barcode-scanner

I am facing this unsolvable problem and would be happy to get your help with it.

I have an iphone app that uses the ZBar barcode scanner. I have a main viewcontroller that calls the ZBar scanner upon a push of a UIButton. Once the scanner has launched and has detected the barcode number, it dismisses itself and I call the results view controller which shows some results of the scanning. My problem is with dismissing the results viewcontroller - from some reason I cant dimiss it and get back to the main view controller in a clean way. My work around was to create a new object of the main view controller and call it, which is a really bad design.

Here is my code - appreciate any help!

Calling the scanner somewhere in the Main Viewcontroller (UIButton action method):

```
ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
UINavigationController *navCntrl1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:reader];
reader.readerDelegate = self;
reader.title = @"Scan Barcode";
reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;
ZBarImageScanner *scanner1 = reader.scanner;
[scanner1 setSymbology: ZBAR_I25 config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to: 0];
[scanner1 setSymbology: ZBAR_QRCODE config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to: 0];
[self presentModalViewController:navCntrl1 animated:YES];
```

The Scanner Delegate method within the main ViewController:

```
//ZBarSDK Finish Scanning
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
  id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
for(symbol in results)
    break;

// EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode data

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

//Calling the Results view controller
Results *resultsViewController = [[Results alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
resultsViewController.tempBarcode = barcode;

UINavigationController *resultsNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:resultsViewController];
resultsNavigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate].window setRootViewController:resultsNavigationController];

 }
```

Here is a place to say that I tried to replace:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate].window setRootViewController:resultsNavigationController];
```

With:

```
[self presentModalViewController:resultsViewController animated:YES];
```

But nothing happens if I do so.

From within the Results ViewController I do this to go back to the main view controller:

```
ViewController *mainViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *mainNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];
mainNavigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;    
[self presentModalViewController:mainNavigationController animated:YES];
```

Instead of just this, which doesnt work:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Thanks for the patience!

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar app that uses ZBar. Here is my analog of your UIButton method:

```
- (void)scanButtonTapped{
    ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
    reader.readerDelegate = self;
    reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

    ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;

    // I need to scan only QR-codes
    [scanner setSymbology:0 config:ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to:0];
    [scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_QRCODE config:ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to:1];
    reader.readerView.zoom = 1.0;

    [self presentModalViewController:reader animated:YES];
    [reader release];
}
```

Here is my imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [info objectForKey:ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;

    for (symbol in results) 
        break;

    // Here I get the QR-code text
    self.qrText = symbol.data;
    NSLog(@"QR-code text = %@",self.qrText);

    // Here I hide scanning View Controller from user
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    // Here I call QR-code text processing logic
    [self ticketCheckOutLogic];
}
```

For calling another UIViewController I can suggest to post a notification after your [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; to your AppDelegate e.g.:

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.barcodeText, @"barcodeText", nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"newBarcodeScanned" object:nil userInfo:options];
```

In application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: you can write something like that:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showResultView:)name:@"newBarcodeScanned" object:nil];
```

... and your showResultView: can be like that:

```
- (void)showResultView:(NSNotification *)notification {
     //Calling the Results view controller
     Results *resultsViewController = [[Results alloc] initWithNibName:@"ResultsView" bundle:nil];
     NSDictionary *dict = [notification userInfo];
     resultsViewController.tempBarcode = [dict objectForKey:@"barcodeText"];
     [self presentModalViewController:resultsViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: my delegate method - (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info is not getting called. any help ?